# Normal system of the least square method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

I'm trying to show the following. $Pa$ is the approximation system of $y$. I want to show that finding the minimmum for the function $$f(a,y)=||Pa-y||_2^2$$
is equivalent to solve the normal system of the least square method $$P^TPa=P^Ty$$

What I thought so far:
I can write $$P^TPa=P^Ty\implies P^T(Pa-y)=0$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=0$$
$$(\sqrt{(Pa-y)^2}^2)'=0 \implies 2(Pa-y)P=0$$

Now I don't see why $$2(Pa-y)P=P^T(Pa-y)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ is a matrix and $a$ and $y$ are column vectors, so $(Pa-y)P$ doesn't really make sense because the sizes don't match up.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\|Pa-y\|^2
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\langle Pa-y,Pa-y\rangle\\
&=\langle Pa-y,P\rangle+\langle P,Pa-y\rangle\\
&=2\langle Pa-y,P\rangle\\
&=2P^T(Pa-y)
\end{align}
$$
not $(Pa-y)P$.

---

Since $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\sqrt{f(a)}=\frac{f'(a)}{2\sqrt{f(a)}}$, we get
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\|Pa-y\|=\frac{P^T(Pa-y)}{\|Pa-y\|}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. But what happens with the factor $2$?

Comment: @MarcZ: If the addendum does not answer your question, let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see the connection between the addendum and the factor 2. When $2P^{t}(Pa-y)$ is the derivative of the quadratic error function, then why is it different to $P^TPa=P^Ty\implies P^T(Pa-y)=0$. I don't understand, what this has to do with the addendum.

Comment: I thought you were wondering why the factor of $2$ was not in the derivative of $\|Pa-y\|$. I didn't think you were concerned about the factor of $2$ in $2P^T(Pa-y)=0$ since $2x=0\iff x=0$. What is it that is bothering you about the factor of $2$?